# Change the default video shortcode

Tags: shortcode

When I select a video file from media library and click on insert in to post button that time it goes like this :

```
[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/C-1-Hello-World1 - Copy - Copy.mp4"][/video]
```

But my requirement is like below:

```
[rtmp_video width="1280" height="720" mp4="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/166/C-1-Hello-World1 - Copy - Copy.mp4"][/rtmp_video]
```

Only for amazon s3 videos I wanted that shortcode

So what should I do for this. I dont know how is this possible

This is what i write in function.php

---

//Shortcode for rtmp distribution video security

```
function rtmp_video($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "src" => ''
    ), $atts));
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $signed_url = getSignedURL($src,60);
        pw_global_js_vars($signed_url);
    }
}
add_shortcode('rtmp_video', 'rtmp_video');
```

---

But i don't know how to apply this

Answer (score 1):

Here's an untested way to override the output of the  `[video]` shortcode, with the output of your custom `rtmp_video()` function, when the mp4 video is hosted on *amazonaws.com*:

```
/**
 * Override the video shortcode output for mp4 hosted on 'amazonaws.com'          
 * with the rtmp_video output.
 *
 * @uses rtmp_video()
 */
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode_override', function( $output, $attr, $content, $instance )
{
    if( 
          isset( $attr['mp4'] ) 
       && 'amazonaws.com' === parse_url( $attr['mp4'], PHP_URL_HOST )
       && function_exists( 'rtmp_video' )
    ) 
        $output = rtmp_video( $attr, $content );

    return $output;

}, 10, 4 );
```

Note that the `extract()` isn't recommended [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400) in general and  it's not clear if your custom `rtmp_video()` callback supports the `mp4` attribute, like you've shown in the shortcode example. A workaround for that could be `$attr['src'] = $attr['mp4'];`

You mentioned that you placed your shortcode in the `function.php`, file. I guess you mean the `functions.php` file in the current theme directory? You should really consider adding it in a custom plugin, because next time you switch themes, your content will not support that shortcode anymore.