# Change the WP Video Shortcode Output

Tags: php, functions

Is it possible to change the structure of the WP video shortcode output that's displayed in post editor after selecting a video from media library and adding it to a post?

I'm trying to change the default shortcode from adding my video urls like this:

```
[video width="3840" height="2160" mp4="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/11111111/11111a111_111111-1.mp4"][/video]
```

To this:

```
[smartvideo src="https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/11111111/11111a111_111111-1.mp4" width="1280" height="720" responsive=true controls=true]
```

The smartvideo shortcode can be the same everytime, only the src url has to be dynamic based on the video's url.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the default video shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218441/change-the-default-video-shortcode)

Comment: Unfortunately, that code doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Nope, can't do that without extraneous effort.